# SQL Case insensitive IN search

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have this Table `"Table"` with content:

```
+--------+
| Serial |
+--------+
| d100m  | <- expected result
| D100M  | <- expected result
| d200m  | <- expected result
| d300L  |
| D400R  |
+--------+
```

There are case inaccurate serial numbers stored.

Currently I am selecting there with a statement like

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE Serial LIKE 'D100M' OR Serial LIKE 'D200M';
```

But isn't there a easier way instead of `OR Serial LIKE OR Serial LIKE OR Serial LIKE` there are alomst 30 numbers i have to compare with.

Something like this

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE Serial LIKE IN ('D100M', 'D200M')
```

Comment: `WHERE Serial IN ('D100M', 'D200M')`

Comment: @SalmanA that doesn't match `d100m`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You could have a separate, additional `Serial_search` column where each value is stored in uppercase and lowercase

Comment: @SalmanA: that very much depends on the DBMS being used. Postgres, Firebird, Oracle, DB2 are case **sensitive** by default.

Comment: @Toshi is your `WHERE Serial LIKE 'D100M' OR Serial LIKE 'D200M'` working as expected i.e. case-insensitive?

Comment: OP you must specify what RDBMS you are using. Because in SQL server you can just change the collation for the query, in Postgresql the question wouldn't have made sense (`LIKE` is case sensitive), in Oracle or DB2 the solution is completely different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
SELECT Serial 
FROM Table 
WHERE upper(Serial) in ('D100M', 'D200M');
```

That won't however use an index on the `serial` column.

So if performance is a concern you would need to create an index on `upper(serial)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE Serial IN ('D100M', 'D200M',<addAllSerialsHereCommaSeparated>)
```

UPDATE:
If all serials should be checked in upper case, you could use:

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE upper(Serial) IN ('D100M', 'D200M',<addAllSerialsHereCommaSeparated>)
```

Comment: How is this case insensitive though?

Comment: If I understand correctly, insensitive means, it is not neccessary to check lower or uppercase. So you can cast all strings to upper case to check, can't you?

Comment: forces a specific case, meaning you don't need to account for lower case, it's a really good poor mans case insensitive check, con is your checks need to be in uppercase but you have to write them anyway so it's a very minor issue

Answer (score 1):

as long as you do not use wildcards or other `like` operator characters, you can use this script:

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE upper(Serial) IN ('D100M', 'D200M')
```

other wise, you need a full text search.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to get the records with ignoring the case.
You can use upper or lower function and do something like:

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE Upper(Serial) IN ('D100M', 'D200M')
```

Or

```
SELECT Serial FROM Table WHERE Lower(Serial) IN ('d100m', 'd200m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query format:

```
select * from dual where upper(DUMMY) in (SELECT upper(x.split_values)
FROM
  (WITH T AS
  (SELECT 'A,B,C,D,E,F' STR FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) SPLIT_VALUES
FROM T
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
  (SELECT LENGTH (REPLACE (STR, ',', NULL)) FROM T
  )
  ) x
)
```

The query in the IN clause converts your comma separated list to rows...the final selection in x.split values is converted to upper and then returned as columns.

finally it is supplied to IN clause as a mini table...

This is Oracle Specific.

in case of MS SQL this link may be useful to perform same ops...:
http://sqljason.com/2010/05/converting-single-comma-separated-row.html

Answer (score 0):

you may check following:

```
SELECT Serial
FROM Table
WHERE (Serial collate SQL_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as)
      IN ('D100M', 'D200M', 'd200m');
```

It should get correct and desired information.